# How to handle clients connections from RabitMQ server application

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm trying to implement an application server just like a chat server using rabbitMq.

Clients connect directly to the rabbit server. the application server should be able to know which clients have been connected and when a client disconnects an event should be fired in the application server.

Is it possible to implement this kind of functionality with Rabbitmq?

Does Rabbitmq have any kind of event dispatching for connection events?(not for clients but for my application server)

I'm using official C# client for Rabbitmq.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.rabbitmq.com/event-exchange.html

Comment: @LutzHorn That the answer of my question.Thanks

Comment: @LutzHorn please put it in the Answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Lutz Horn already said, you can use the `event exchange` plugin to emit events related to connections, channels and much more.

Reference: https://www.rabbitmq.com/event-exchange.html
GitHub: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-event-exchange

You have to create a queue, so that the event exchange routes these events to this queue. And have a consumer that listens to this queue. I have added a link to the one that I am using.

Code: https://gist.github.com/sathishbabu96/35821a6b1e90daa76d3dd76bef084788